# .HTACCESS - Go to page if exists, redirect if enter only domain, redirect if enter folder doesn't exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have need for creative htaccess file:

**when user enters file that exists - ok.**

> -- i.e http://mydomain.com/install/program32.zip =
>   /install/program32.zip

**when user enters the domain only - redirect download file**

> -- i.e http://mydomain.com = /myfile.apk

**when user enters a directory (folder) that doesn't exist - redirect to specific PHP file.**

> -- i.e http://mydomain.com/custom1 = /manager.php?param=custom1 or
>   /manager.php?custom1

We currently have 1 & 2 working. Now we are trying to add #3. Currently the htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^$ /myfile.apk [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^$ /myfile.apk [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /manager.php?param=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you. Ugh. I dont know why but I have never been able to fully grasp htaccess logic. Thank you for saving me the heartburn.